# Why is this not correctly detecting an integer overflow?

Tags: java, assert, assertion

Why is this not correctly detecting an integer overflow?

```
private static float calc(float a, int b){
    float sum = a;

    for (int i = 1; i <= b; i++){
        assert Math.abs(a) <= Integer.MAX_VALUE : "Overflow";
        sum = sum * sum;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: `x` doesn't change in the loop. Also, `Math.pow(a, b)`

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68931547/how-do-i-detect-underflow-and-overflow) looks like an exact duplicate, with the exact same bug.

Comment: Try `assert Float.isFinite(sum) : "Overflow";`

Answer (score 1):

The `assert` statement uses the variable `a`, which never changes. It should use `sum`.

By default, assertions are disabled at runtime, so you'll need to run `java` with the `-enableassertions` (or `-ea`) switch.

Example usage:

```
class TestOverflow<T> {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(calc(2.0f, 6));
    }


    private static float calc(float a, int b){
        float sum = a;

        for (int i = 1; i <= b; i++){
            assert Math.abs(sum) <= Integer.MAX_VALUE : "Overflow";
            sum = sum * sum;
        }
        return sum;
    }
}
```

Compiled and run:

```
$ java -ea -cp out/production/scratchpad/ TestOverflow 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError: Overflow
        at TestOverflow.calc(TestOverflow.java:12)
        at TestOverflow.main(TestOverflow.java:4)
```